# PHP code to download images from xml file to local folder

Tags: php, xml

I wanted to download all the images in an xml file (fabfurnish.xml) to a local folder (output). After editing the code below according to **@user1978142** i got the desired result. Thanks.

```
<?php 
$xml = simplexml_load_file('input/fabfurnish.xml'); // your xml
foreach($xml->product as $url) {
    $url = (string) $url->image;
    $filename = basename($url); // get the filename
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "file <strong>$filename</strong> already exists <br/>";
    } else {
        $img = file_get_contents($url); // get the image from the url
        file_put_contents('output/'.$filename, $img); // create a file and feed the image
        echo "file <strong>$filename</strong> created <br/>";
    }
 }

 ?>
```

This is the actual xml file i am working with:

https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/a88c2605cf038f8cc72603a0cf33904620140711034115/2ce9841bc9fd57063a0919de5f46862120140711034115/c1adbb

Comment: change it to `$v->image`, also change `$xml-->url` to `$xml->url`, never trust a copy and paste, also your formatting/indentation is odd.

Comment: i have changed i, but still not working. what might be the reason.

Comment: Can you show an example of the xml

Comment: @BrianCoolidge There was no need to be rude with your original edit comment.

Comment: @BrianCoolidge thnx I will take care next time. I am new here and don't know all the functionality of this site. Sorry for that

Comment: This is a part of the XML feed. I want to download all the image links in it with the above mentioned php code. but it still not working after correcting the errors

Comment: You should update (edit) the question with the changes you've made, so that we can see the code as it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this is quite straightforward. Sample:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('fabfurnish.xml'); // your xml
foreach($xml->product as $url) {
    $url = (string) $url->image;
    $filename = basename($url); // get the filename
    if(file_exists($filename)) {
        echo "file <strong>$filename</strong> already exists <br/>";
    } else {
        $img = file_get_contents($url); // get the image from the url
        file_put_contents($filename, $img); // create a file and feed the image
        echo "file <strong>$filename</strong> created <br/>";
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a huge product details in xml. this is just a samlpe with 2 product details. i think your code will work with one product. plz suggest for a multiple products

Comment: @Kumarjit try the revision again, i used your xml example above

Comment: @Kumarjit by the way your edit on the xml malformed it: `<image>http://1.fimg.in/p/bohemia-crystal-5933-2724-1-zoom.jpg</image` `<-- missing ">"`

Comment: not working. im posting the actual xml feed. plz see if you can come up with some solution

Comment: @Kumarjit check another edit, i used your xml as a string, working on my end just fine. if this still doesn't work, then no one could replicate your problems

Comment: plz see my new xml post

Comment: your code is working with the sample xml i posted earlier but not with the actual xml file. plz see the file i have posted with the link

Comment: @Kumarjit it's still working, a little bit slow since that file has tons of content, if this still doesn't work, check for file permissions if your php is allowed to create files.

Comment: ok wher shall i pute ur code. i side the function, and delete the rest? plz check and reply me. i am updating my code with ur code

Comment: and where your output will be, in the same folder?

Comment: plz check, i have updated my code with yours

Comment: @Kumarjit yes it should be saved on the same place where you executed the php, anyway i have given all the help you need, i think there is nothing more to discuss since i think this is the simplest and straightforward approach, that's why this has been closed. if it still won't work then you should write your own way.

Comment: ya thnx for your help its working

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse specific xml file like your sample, you can edit as following code in getImagesFromXML($xmlurl).

```
foreach ($xml->product as $product) {
    foreach($product->image as $url) {
       $tmp = explode("/", $url);
       save($url, end($tmp), "output/");
    }
}
```

Comment: made the changes. Still not working

Comment: @Kumarjit hmm. I already test it and it's working. Would you give me error code?

Comment: please see the code above. i have made the changes. see if somethings wrong

Comment: there is no error code. i am not getting any images in the output folder after running the code

Comment: @Kumarjit Can you see "The file output/angel-3322-29862-1-zoom.jpg does not exist" message? Please check output folder. You can find it.

Comment: ya if i save this much part of the xml then its working, but my xml file is huge with many product details. its not working with the actual file please suggest

Comment: ya if i save this much part of the xml then its working, but my xml file is huge with many product details. its not working with the actual file

Comment: @Kumarjit Oh, i see. you want to get multiple product image from XML :) I fixed very simple way.

Comment: can you please suggest a way?

Comment: i have added one more product to the xml sample. so that you can test it. plz suggest

Comment: @Kumarjit I fixed your primary code. Try it again.

Comment: but not with the actual data :(

Comment: im posting the actual xml feed. plz see if you can come up with some solution

Comment: plz see my new xml post